# Конвертирование ASCII в UTF8

Tags: sqlite, кодировка, c++

Помогите разобраться с кодировкой при добавлении записи с русскими буквами в DB SQLite.
Информация которую я записываю в базу имеет кодировку ASCII 8bit, а база SQLite испотзует utf8. Соответсвенно в базе я вижу вместо русского текста знаки вопроса.

Вопрос. Как преобразовать текст из ASCII в UTF8 на С++?

Comment: Вариантов - мульон, вы б хоть платформу/компилятор указали. `man iconv`, например.

Comment: ASCII вообще то это 7 бит, старший 8-й бит используется по разному для различных русских кодировок: Win-1251, CP-866, KOI-8 - везде по разному. Так что укажите точную русскую кодировку

Comment: компилятор MSVS2010

Comment: [FAQ, однако](http://wiki.shelek.ru/index.php/FAQ:WinAPI_VCPP:%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_windows-1251_%D0%B8_UTF-8)

Comment: как мне подсказали, кодировка текста, который я пытаюсь записать в базу, зависит от настроек винды (Язык и региональные настройки, во вкладке допольнительно выбираю язык Русский для программ не поддерживающих юникод) какая именно кодировка там нигде не указано.

Comment: Ой, ссылка кривая получилась, sorry. Вот [правильная](http://wiki.shelek.ru/index.php/FAQ:WinAPI_VCPP:%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_windows-1251_%D0%B8_UTF-8). В общем, ни разу не проблема получить текущую кодовую страницу, это азы. Читайте справочник по Windows API, иначе так и будете спотыкаться на каждом мелком шаге.

P.S. Да что за ерудна, ссылка какая-то не та получатся :( Попробую в ответе вставить.

Comment: В таком случае там cp1251. Проще всего проверить браузером.

Например в Firefox, открываете локальный *тектовый* файл с русскими символами, в меню выбираете View/Character Encodig/... и смотрите, угадали или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка

P.S. Нет! И здесь ссылка превращается непонятно во что... Ещё раз: http://goo.gl/KkroPA

Answer (score 0):

Использовал библиотеку [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkStringRef.html)

Там все интуитивно понятно

```
#include "chilkat-9.4.1-x86-vc10\include\CkString.h"

std::string ansi2utf8(const std::string& s)
{
   CkString str;
   str.put_Utf8(false);
   str.append(s.c_str());
   str.getUtf8();
   return string(str.getUtf8());
}
```